# Given any two points $x, y \in X$ there exists connected set $A$ such that $x, y \in A$. Then $X$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Let $X$ be a (metric) space such that given any two points $x, y \in X$ there exists connected set $A$ such that $x, y \in A$. Then $X$ is connected.

Let us consider a continuous function $f : X \to \{-1,+1\}$. We first choose $p \in X$. With out loss of generality we consider $f(p) =1$. If $x \in X$ then by hypothesis there exists a connected subset $A$ in $X$ such that $x,p \in A$. Since $A$ is connected $f(x) = 1$. Since $x$ is arbitrary in $X$ so the function $f$ is constant proving the fact that $X$ is connected.

Is the proof correct?

Comment: Shouldn't $y$ be $p$ here?

Comment: Another approach is to assume $X$ is not connected, so essentially your $f$ is onto, and deduce a contradiction from some $p$ with $f(p) = 1$ and $q$ with $f(q) = -1$. But that's essentially the same idea. Your proof is OK (with the one edit I made), and which @tattwamasiamrutam suggested.